# Problem fetching more than the first row from SQLite DB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, sqlite

I am creating an application which first checks whether the user is valid or not by checking data from an SQLite database. I have created a table named `loginchk` in the database with three rows and two columns in it, `uname` and `pass`.

When I run the application and enter the username and password values in my text fields, it checks if the username and password are in the database. If they are not, it will present an alert view that says "Please enter correct username".

In my code there is a problem: it reads only the first row, i.e., when I enter the username and password values that are in the first row it succeeds, and all the other values that I enter do not work.

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

```
#import "loginAppDelegate.h"
#import "global.h" 
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "logincontroller.h" 
@implementation loginAppDelegate 
@synthesize window; 
@synthesize loginView; 
//databaseName=@"login.sqlite";
 -(void) chekAndCreateDatabase 
{   
BOOL success;   
//sqlite3  *databaseName=@"login.sqlite";  
 NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
 NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);   
NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString  *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent"login.sqlite"];   success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPathatabasePath];  
 if(success)return;      
NSString *databasePathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent"login.sqlite"];
      [fileManager copyItemAtPathatabasePathFromApp toPathatabasePath error:nil];   [fileManager release]; 
} 

-(void) Data 
{     
 Gpass=@"";   
Guname=@""; 
sqlite3_stmt *detailStmt=nil;    
//sqlite3  *databaseName;      
NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString  *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent{angry_smile}"login.sqlite"];
[self chekAndCreateDatabase];
      sqlite3 *database;   
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)
 {    
   if (detailStmt==nil)
    {       
      const char *sql= "select *from Loginchk"; //where uname='%?'and password='%?'";       //NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat{angry_smile}"SELECT * FROM Loginchk WHERE uname ='%@' and password ='%@' ",Uname.text,Password.text];      
 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql,-1,&detailStmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) 
{                                 
      sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt,1,[Gunameq UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT); 
                    sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt,2,[Gpassq UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);                  
if (SQLITE_DONE!= sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) 


{                    
  Guname=[NSString stringWithUTF8Stringchar*)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,0)];        

Gpass =[NSString stringWithUTF8Stringchar*)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,1)];                    

NSLog(@"'%@'",Guname);         
  NSLog(@"'%@'",Gpass);         }     
  }       sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);    
 }   
}   sqlite3_close(database); 
  }
```

This my login controller; here I am calling my app delegate's function `data`:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{     
 Gpassq=Password.text; 
  Gunameq=Uname.text;
      NSLog(@"%@%@",Gunameq,Gpassq);
   loginAppDelegate *appDelegate =(loginAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];  
 [appDelegate Data];   
   if ([Uname.text isEqualToString:Guname]&&[Password.text isEqualToString:Gpass])
 {         
 UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Success" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
    [alert show]; 
    [alert release];
   }     
  else
 {  
    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"PleaseEnterCorrectUserName and password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
[alert show];      
[alert release];  
  } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if (SQLITE_DONE!= sqlite3_step(detailStmt))
```

with

```
while  (SQLITE_DONE!= sqlite3_step(detailStmt))
```

**Update 1**

use this code -

```
-(void) Data 
{     
    Gpass=@"";   
    Guname=@""; 
    sqlite3_stmt *detailStmt=nil;    
    //sqlite3  *databaseName;      
    NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString  *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.sqlite"];
    [self chekAndCreateDatabase];


    sqlite3 *database;   
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {    

        const char *sql= "select *from Loginchk"; //where uname='%?'and password='%?'";       //NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat{angry_smile}"SELECT * FROM Loginchk WHERE uname ='%@' and password ='%@' ",Uname.text,Password.text];      
        sqlite3_stmt *detailStmt;   
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql,-1,&detailStmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) 
        {                                 
            while(sqlite3_step(detailStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {

                Guname=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,0)];        
                Gpass =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,1)];                    

                NSLog(@"'%@'",Guname);         
                NSLog(@"'%@'",Gpass);         

            }     

        }   

        sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);    
        sqlite3_close(database); 

    }   


}
```

Comment: removing the if and add while not checks my condition it directly get into the else part

Comment: are you sure you have multiple rows in your database.. print the database path and open it using some sqlite client and check the table..

Comment: I can't believe this is not working .. I tested this code!!! you must have some other problem!

Comment: yes it will go in the else part.. because you logic is wrong.... Guname and Gpass will only hold the last username and password.. you should check username and password in "buttonPressed" function.. just open the database there and check for entered username and password with this query -  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Loginchk where username = '%@' and password=%@",username.text,password.text];

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\-(void) Data 
{     
 Gpass=@"";   
Guname=@""; 
sqlite3_stmt *detailStmt=nil;    
//sqlite3  *databaseName;      
NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString  *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent{angry_smile}"login.sqlite"];
[self chekAndCreateDatabase];
      sqlite3 *database;   
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&database)==SQLITE_OK)
 {    
   if (detailStmt==nil)
    {       
      const char *sql= "select *from Loginchk"; //where uname='%?'and password='%?'";       //NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat{angry_smile}"SELECT * FROM Loginchk WHERE uname ='%@' and password ='%@' ",Uname.text,Password.text];      
 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql,-1,&detailStmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) 
{                                 
      sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt,1,[Gunameq UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT); 
                    sqlite3_bind_text(detailStmt,2,[Gpassq UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);                  
// Loop through the results
            while(sqlite3_step(detailStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {


{                    
  Guname=[NSString stringWithUTF8Stringchar*)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,0)];        

Gpass =[NSString stringWithUTF8Stringchar*)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt,1)];                    

NSLog(@"'%@'",Guname);         
  NSLog(@"'%@'",Gpass);         }     
  }       sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);    
 }   
}   sqlite3_close(database); 
  }
```